# Angular material. How to create md-select with icon?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I added icon in md-option and i want to see it with the selected language. 
Here is my code

```
<md-select id="countryString" name="countryString"   [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry" >
          <md-option [value]="'en'">
            <img src="../../assets/images/icons/en.png" />Англійська</md-option>
          <md-option [value]="'ua'">
            <img src="../../assets/images/icons/ukr.png" />Українська</md-option>
          <md-option [value]="'ru'">
            <img src="../../assets/images/icons/ru.png" />Російська</md-option>
        </md-select>
```

I can't show img here my ask with one: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/10694

Comment: Works for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/njuaiWMnebN00dQCYcxh?p=preview

Comment: Is your relative path to the assets correct? Do you see the `img` tags when you inspect element?

Comment: Update in my answer

Comment: Sorry, but your plunker answer icon not show with selected option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a container element with a an `img` element that has a conditional `src` attribute.

```
<!-- only show when the user has selected a value -->
<div *ngIf="selectedCountry">
    <img src="../../assets/images/icons/{{selectedCountry}}.png"/>
</div>

<!-- your select element -->
<md-select ...
```

You might need to wrap those elements in a `flex` container or using float.